# Interventions during the current Corona crisis: Government credits

Tags: political-economy, financial-crises, credit

In the light of the current public health crisis caused by COVID-19, I would like to know more about how government or central bank interventions are supposed to influence and limit the economic fallout.

- How will interest-free government credits for businesses help to cover short and medium term losses and influence their financial health?
- How are those credits supposed to be repaid if the current situation results in an economic downturn?
- How can governments refinance those credits?
- What are the short and long-term macroeconomic implications of such an intervention? (optionally: given to the current situation in the European Union)

If possible, base your answer on applicable historical examples, economic principles or (your own) expert opinion. Pointing to relevant sources and literature is also highly appreciated.

Stay healthy!